# What is the expected error code if a route can't be created?

Tags: rest, geolocation, here-api

I am using the REST version of the [Here Maps API](https://developer.here.com/documentation). It seems that if I provide a destination location (latitude, longitude) that cannot be routed the API is returning a HTTP Error of 400 (Bad Request).

I was under the impression I would get a 200 response code but no data would be returned.

For example if I send a request to the API with New York as the source and Paris, France as the destination the API returns a 400 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

The response codes of RESTful APIs are determined by the API developers. From what you are saying it seems that Here Maps does not know how to route someone over the Atlantic Ocean and is telling you that by returning a 400 Bad Request response instead of providing a 200 response. [Http Status Code Explanations](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

You'll want to dig into the api documentation, perhaps the API is expecting two points that can be routed by land and you can supply a way to indicate that by-air and/or by-sea routes are okay also.

Alternatively, you will need check the response status from the Here Maps API first on your program before you attempt to consume it as a 200 status and if you receive a 400 status then you can communicate that there was an error to your end user which you could inform them of the reasons why a particular request might fail. Such a source and destination on continents not linked by a land mass.

(This reminds me of how Google Maps used to provide driving directions which would tell you to kayak across oceans, not sure if still does that but illustrates a way to resolve a by-land route that cannot be taken only by land.)

Comment: Yes, Azeanne, that is what I did (display an error that may be related to the 400 as cannot retrieve route - which may not be accurate!).  And I did check the API documentation which does indicate that a 200 should be returned without the requested data.